# How do I Capture dd command output

Tags: io-redirection, dd, file-descriptors

I have a test script, which is used to estimate the filesize for a particular oracle export dumpfile. Content of the script is:

```
 mknod exp.pipe p
 dd if=exp.pipe of=/dev/null bs=1024 &
 exp system/sys123@testorcl file=exp.pipe parfile=exptest1.par
```

And the output is something like below on screen, which needs to be captured in a file or variable required for further computation.

```
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully without warnings.
12+0 records in.
12+0 records out.
```

I need to compute the values 12 and 0 in either of Records in or Records out, whichever is feasible, either through a variable or a file.

Answer (score 1):

I start same way

```
mknod exp.pipe p
wc -c < exp.pipe > pipe.c 2>&1 &
dd if=/dev/zero of=exp.pipe count=5

5+0 records in
5+0 records out
2560 bytes (2,6 kB) copied, 0,001472 s, 1,7 MB/s
```

then

```
cat pipe.c
2560
```

this is not quiet what you ask, but it will give you the size of the export.

I don't have man for `exp` utility, but in the old time, there use to be a preview option, which (with proper parsing) might give you a hint about its size.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect standard error

```
dd if=exp.pipe of=/dev/null bs=1024 2> dd
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'd tried that, but did not work, infact, the script gets hung and when cancelled using Ctrl+C, the files (exp.pipe and output.txt / dd as in above) are created of 0 bytes